# Django - How to gruouping column datatble in django?

Tags: django, datatable, grouping

I have script for my datatable. So, I store my attribute from API and I need to grouping column into one column. Can django do that? As long I know, that could but in JQuery, but it's impossible to bring my datatable to JQuery basics so many attributes.

Here is my code :

```
    ['No. Telp <br/>Nasabah 1','notelp1_debitur',''],
    ['No. Telp <br/>Pasangan 2','notelp2_pasangan',''],
    ['No. Telp <br/>Pasangan 1','notelp1_pasangan',''],
    ['No. Telp <br/>Nasabah 2','notelp2_debitur',''],
```

And I want to be grouping it like this :

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try and get help with English. You could write title&question in your first language and try and see what https://translate.google.com/ makes of it. Use a spelling checker when posting in a foreign language.

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to django or any other backend frameworks how we are gonna show the data in frontend.
this is the html table, and how to put data in that table to create something like the photo.
you could create a table, or two.
for a cell of html table you could specify the col(s), and row(s) it needs to capture. read about this on w3schools.com